# Is using single api endpoint to fetch multiple model data a bad practice?

Tags: api, http, server, api-design

Our mobile app has recently started to have latency problems. The main reason for this is because on every app open, it tries to sync with the server and fires ~10 api endpoint calls to fetch each model.

For example,

```
GET /api/profile
GET /api/locations/all
GET /api/positions/all
... 10 more
```

So I'm trying to implement one api that client can call to sync with server data more easily.

Say,

```
GET /api/user
```

which will return data in json format like:

```
{
  "profile": ...,
  "locations": ...,
  "positions": ...,
  ...
}
```

But I'm worried that this is not a good practice as I haven't seen many software that does this.

Is using single api endpoint to fetch multiple model data at once a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint can return whatever makes sense to you. You are the one who defines the model.

The larger question in your case is whether it will resolve your latency issue. Will one endpoint perform that much better than 10? It depends.

Another option to consider is not hitting all these endpoints on every app open. Can the data be cached on the device for a time and refreshed periodically?

Those are some things to think about.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some details have been left out. In fact, the models have dependency relationship so not all of them can be fetched all at once but rather sequentially. Our software has hard constraint on data being synced with server at all time.